# Getting HTTP headers with Node.js

Tags: node.js

Is there a built in way to get the headers of a specific address via node.js?

something like,

```
var headers = getUrlHeaders("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

would return

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60.
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8.
Content-Encoding: gzip.
Expires: Sat, 07 May 2011 17:32:38 GMT.
Last-Modified: Sat, 07 May 2011 17:31:38 GMT.
Vary: *.
Date: Sat, 07 May 2011 17:31:37 GMT.
Content-Length: 32516.
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

This sample code should work:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {method: 'HEAD', host: 'stackoverflow.com', port: 80, path: '/'};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  }
);
req.end();
```

Comment: You might note, that (depending on the server and the header fields you’re trying to get) you might actually need a "full" GET request, as some servers don’t include certain header fields, like `set-cookie`, in responses from HEAD requests.

Answer (score 23):

Try to look at [http.get](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/http.html#http.get) and [response headers](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/http.html#response.headers).

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: 'stackoverflow.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

  for(var item in res.headers) {
    console.log(item + ": " + res.headers[item]);
  }
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: This might work fine for small files, but it's better to use HTTP HEAD if you don't plan to do anything with the body of the data.

Answer (score 21):

Using the excellent [`request`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) module:

```
var request = require('request');
  request("http://stackoverflow.com", {method: 'HEAD'}, function (err, res, body){
  console.log(res.headers);
});
```

You can change the method to `GET` if you wish, but using `HEAD` will save you from getting the entire response body if you only wish to look at the headers.

Comment: This will get the entire body! Imagine you want the header to decide whether you want to get the url content or it's over the size limit. This 3 lines for a url to a 5 MB PDF will download the entire pdf  body then it will show you the header! As the name refers, header must be at the beginning not at the end of operation. I forgot to mention you can easily add {method: 'HEAD'} after url as an option and just get the header.

Comment: What is excellent about a library that just provides a thin layer over something that was already easy to use?

Comment: Not for this particular case, but request is downloaded half a million times every day. It supports streaming, all forms of auth and has many more features.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my contribution, that deals with any URL using http or https, and use Promises.

```
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const url = require('url')

function getHeaders(myURL) {
  const parsedURL = url.parse(myURL)
  const options = {
    protocol: parsedURL.protocol,
    hostname: parsedURL.hostname,
    method: 'HEAD',
    path: parsedURL.path
  }
  let protocolHandler = (parsedURL.protocol === 'https:' ? https : http)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let req = protocolHandler.request(options, (res) => {
      resolve(res.headers)
    })
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e)
    })
    req.end()
  })
}

getHeaders(myURL).then((headers) => {
  console.log(headers)
})
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how you might do this with Node, but the general idea would be to send an [HTTP HEAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_HEAD#Request_methods) request to the URL you're interested in.

> #### HEAD
>
> Asks for the response identical to the one that would correspond to a GET request, but without the response body. This is useful for retrieving meta-information written in response headers, without having to transport the entire content.

---

Something like this, based it on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617541/making-an-http-request-using-node-js-throws-eafnosupport):

```
var cli = require('cli');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

cli.parse();

cli.main(function(args, opts) {
        this.debug(args[0]);

        var siteUrl = url.parse(args[0]);
        var site = http.createClient(80, siteUrl.host);
        console.log(siteUrl);

        var request = site.request('HEAD', siteUrl.pathname, {'host' : siteUrl.host})
        request.end();

        request.on('response', function(response) {
                response.setEncoding('utf8');
                console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
                response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                        console.log("DATA: " + chunk);
                });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I had some problems with `http.get`; so I switched to the lib `request`:

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://blog.mynotiz.de/';

var options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'HEAD'
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            return console.error('upload failed:', error);
        }

        if (response.headers['content-length']) {
            var file_size = response.headers['content-length'];
            console.log(file_size);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I was just about the post the same alternative response, because `http`'s promises were giving me crap. +1

Comment: The idea of node community is to use this module that perfectly fits your needs.