# Watch remote file for file size changes

Tags: node.js

Is there a good way to use watchFile on a file which is located on other webserver without downloading it? 
If not, then how can I check the file size changes of a remote file without downloading it?

Comment: With an HTTP `HEAD` request, inspecting the `Content-Length` in the response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do an HTTP HEAD request.  A HEAD request is a GET that requests the HTTP Header only and not the body.  Having the header, you could read the Content-Length or the Date attribute.  (However Content-Length isn't always set correctly.)

Here is how to do HEAD requests with node.js: [Getting HTTP headers with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922842/getting-http-headers-with-node-js)