# Stop downloading the data in nodejs request

Tags: node.js, httprequest, httpresponse

How can we stop the remaining response from a server - 
For eg.

```
http.get(requestOptions, function(response){

//Log the file size;
console.log('File Size:', response.headers['content-length']);

// Some code to download the remaining part of the response?

}).on('error', onError);
```

I just want to log the file size and not waste my bandwidth in downloading the remaining file. Does nodejs automatically handles this or do I have to write some special code for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just want fetch the size of the file, it is best to use [HTTP HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), which returns only the response headers from the server without the body.

You can make a HEAD request in Node.js like this:

```
var http = require("http"),
    // make the request over HTTP HEAD
    // which will only return the headers
    requestOpts = {
    host: "www.google.com",
    port: 80,
    path: "/images/srpr/logo4w.png",
    method: "HEAD"
};

var request = http.request(requestOpts, function (response) {
    console.log("Response headers:", response.headers);
    console.log("File size:", response.headers["content-length"]);
});

request.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

// send the request
request.end();
```

EDIT:

I realized that I didn't *really* answer your question, which is essentially "How do I terminate a request early in Node.js?". You can terminate any request in the middle of processing by calling response.destroy():

```
var request = http.get("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png", function (response) {
    console.log("Response headers:", response.headers);

    // terminate request early by calling destroy()
    // this should only fire the data event only once before terminating
    response.destroy();

    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
        console.log("received data chunk:", chunk); 
    });
});
```

You can test this by commenting out the the destroy() call and observing that in a full request two chunks are returned. Like mentioned elsewhere, however, it is more efficient to simply use HTTP HEAD.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. How is it different than response.end() and when should I use that?

Comment: One more thing, if I dont bind a listener to the 'data' event will the data still be transferred ? I mean my bandwidth will get wasted unnecessarily?

Comment: Yes, the data will still be sent down to the client even if you don't handle the "data" event.

Comment: Regarding the end() vs. destroy() question, the response object doesn't have an end() in this context.

Comment: This is a follow up question - How do I end the response before getting the response object?

Comment: @RobertMitchell Thanks for posting the answer to the question as well as what he should actually do. This is the 1st SO hit on a Google search for `node cancel http get request` and it would be a shame if it didn't actually answer that question just because it wasn't what should be done in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to perform a **HEAD** request instead of a get

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6001507/1095114)

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
    method: 'HEAD', 
    host: 'stackoverflow.com', 
    port: 80, 
    path: '/'
};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    var fileSize = res.headers['content-length']
    console.log(fileSize)
  }
);
req.end();
```

Comment: Thanks Noah, I was not aware of this approach.