# JavaScript make a headers only call

Tags: javascript, node.js

How does one make a call in JS to get only the header details for a remote asset? I would like to check the size of the image before deciding to use it

I'm looking for a JS equivalent of:

```
curl -s --head 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, pick an HTTP client library. Then use the HEAD method.

e.g.

```
const head_request_promise = axios({
  method: 'head',
  url: '/user/12345',
});
```

Comment: Or also just the built-in `require('https')`

Comment: @CristianTraìna — There are many libraries they could pick.

Comment: But this doesn't require any dependence :)

Answer (score 0):

this question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922842/getting-http-headers-with-node-js) also

If you want to use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) :

```js
var request = require('request');

request("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png", {method: 'HEAD'}, function (err, res, body){
  console.log(res.headers);
});
```

If you want to use [node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch):

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png')
.then(res => console.log(res.headers.raw()))
```